# Querying two tables where one returns duplicates. Need to limit one, but not the other

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying two tables.  table `page` holds info and `page_images` holds images.  In `page_images` I store all image meta data and the page url_title so it can be associate to the  table `page`.  When I query the info and images I get a duplicate results for `page_images` because theres multiple images for each page.  How can I limit 1 for `page_images` while querying both `page` and `page_images`?

This is the shortened query :

```
SELECT page.url_title,
page.short_title,
page_images.image_loc -- This returns duplicate results
FROM page, page_images
WHERE page.language = '$lang' AND
page.category = '$category' AND
page.url_title != '$page' AND
page.url_title = page_images.page_title
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: UPDATED, you can see I limit 20.  I'll have duplicates because there's usually 4 images for each page.  Each image is stored in it's own row in the table `page_images`.  I want only one image from `page_images` while still retrieving 20 overall pages.  So, ultimately 20 `page` results with one `page_images` result associated for all 20 results.  Sorry, I'm explaining this weird.

Comment: What is the criteria for the one image out of four returned for each page?

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to pull one result use LIMIT 1

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are missing an `INNER JOIN`.
Try:

```
SELECT page.url_title,
page.short_title,
page_images.image_loc -- This returns duplicate results
FROM page inner join page_images
  on page.id = page_images.page_id
WHERE page.language = '$lang' AND
page.category = '$category'
```

Where page.id is the Primary Key of the page table, and page.page_id is the Foreign Key of the page_images table.

Comment: And why did this answer receive a down vote? The original question has been modified. The OP is not actually receiving duplicates, but valid records from the page_images table...the OP should probably change this to a group by query and use MAX on the image_loc field